# Dojo grid implementation issue in zend

Tags: sql, zend-framework, dojo

I have really big problem cannot implement dojo grid in zend.

Here is the my script

`[View]`

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl() . '/scirpts/dojo/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css'); ?>
<?php $this->dojo()->enable(); 
    $this->dojo()->requireModule('dojox.data.QueryReadStore')
                     ->requireModule('dojox.grid.DataGrid');
?>
<div id="view-content">
<?php $this->tabContainer()->captureStart('tabcontainer', array(), array('style' => 'width:100%;height:400px;')) ?>

    <?php $this->contentPane()->captureStart('tab1', array(), array('title' => 'User Manager')); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" >    
      var structure = [ 
            { field: 'id', name: 'UserID', width: '50px' },
            { field: 'username', name : 'User Name', width: '100px' },
            { field: 'email', name : 'E Mail', width: '200px'}
         ]; 
    </script>
    <span dojoType="dojox.data.QueryReadStore" jsId="users" url="/users/loaduser"></span>
    <div id="grid1" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="users" structure="structure"></div> 

    <?php echo $this->contentPane()->captureEnd('tab1'); ?>
<?php echo $this->tabContainer()->captureEnd('tabcontainer'); ?>
</div>
```

`Controller`

```
 public function loaduserAction()
    {
        // Load current data.
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        $user = new Application_Model_Users();
        $users = $user->getUsers();
        $dojoData = new Zend_Dojo_Data('id', $users, 'id');
        echo $dojoData->toJson();
    }
```

`[Layout]`

```
<?php
 if($this->dojo()->isEnabled()) {

        $this->dojo()-> setDjConfigOption('usePlainJson',true)

                  -> addStylesheetModule("dijit.themes.tundra")
                  -> setLocalPath($this->baseUrl('/scripts/dojo/dojo/dojo.js'));

        echo $this->dojo();

    }

?>   

    <body id="page1" class="tundra">
```

`[Bootstrap]`

```
$view = new Zend_View();
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    $view->navigation = array();
    $view->subnavigation = array();


    $view->addHelperPath('Zend/Dojo/View/Helper/', 'Zend_Dojo_View_Helper'); 
    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer(); 
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
```

It does't show anything and I checked the javascript error nothing, this is one of good tutorial I have found in the net, But nothing seems to work. I am really frustrated.  I need your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If column names in dojox.grid.DataGrid are displayed, You need check retrieved json. Else check CSS of dojox.grid.DataGrid. Usually, You need explicitly specify the width and height for dojox.grid.DataGrid, like this:

```
style="width: 800px; height: 500px"
```